# What does [indeterminate] property exactly do in Angular Material components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have used ssome of the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples) components and there is a property called `[indeterminate]` that I have serached on the web, but there is not a good explanations what exactly it does. So, could you tell me what it does in the following example?

```
<section class="example-section">
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin">Check me!</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [disabled]="true">Disabled</mat-checkbox>
</section>

<section class="example-section">
  <span class="example-list-section">
    <mat-checkbox class="example-margin"
                  [checked]="allComplete"
                  [indeterminate]="someComplete()"
                  (change)="setAll($event.checked)">
      {{task.name}}
    </mat-checkbox>
  </span>
  <span class="example-list-section">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let subtask of task.subtasks">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="subtask.completed"
                      [color]="subtask.color"
                      (ngModelChange)="updateAllComplete()">
          {{subtask.name}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </span>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indeterminate` means that the checkbox is neither checked nor unchecked, kind of the middle.

As you can see from the docs, it looks like this: [image]

This is often used when for example, you have a list of stuff that can be checked/unchecked, and they are grouped with a parent (e.g. TreeView).

The parent will be checked if all its children are checked, unchecked if all its children are unchecked and `indeterminate` if some of its children are checked.

The docs also have an example of that:
[image]